# How to use the input of a sidebar form and storing it as a global variable in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use what I type into a sidebar in Google Sheets as a global variable (so that I can use that value in a variety of different functions later on in the script).

Using the `.gs` and `.html` code below, I can pass the input to one other function (which is the `saveValue` function), but I can't figure out how to store that value permanently, or at least until I place in another value using the sidebar.

```js
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function sidebar() {
    var temp = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    temp.setTitle('Title');
    var html = temp.evaluate();
    ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function saveValue(inValue) {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> This is a test</p>
    <br>
    <input id='input-one' type='text'>
    <label form='input-one'>Input</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id='save-values'>Save Values</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    <script>
      document.getElementById('save-values').addEventListener('click',function(){
      var inValue = document.getElementById('input-one').value();
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().saveValue(inValue);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you plan to store the global variables?

Comment: @Cooper , it looks there is the way to store variables: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties

Comment: I'm aware of that but the question was directed to the OP.  I have a  global object the performs a lazy load drawing data from a hash table on a spreadsheet along with the object from Properties Service.  The question was meant to motivate the OP to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quotas of properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

```js
const p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
p.setProperty('key', inValue);
/* load with
p.getProperty('key');
*/
```

---

If you do not want to overwrite and to store all values, you may consider using:

Array

```js
let array = p.getProperty('key');
if (!array) { array = []; }
else { array = JSON.parse(array); }
array.push(inValue);
p.setProperty('key', JSON.stringify(array));
```

Increment keys

```js
const count = p.getProperty('count') || 0;
p.setProperty(`key${count + 1}`, inValue);
```

But I suggest to store in a sheet in this case.